# Problem iterating an array with empty spaces on JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined

Sorry about my english.

Im new at Javascript and i'm trying to clean an array. For example:

```
Input:

-Hello world!
-
-123
-
-abc

Output:

-Hello world!
-123
-abc
```

Actualy, if I try with `array.forEach(item => {console.log(item);}`  it works.

But when I do something like:

```js
if(item === "" || item === undefined || item === null){
array.forEach(function(value, index){

array.splice(index, 1);

} }
```

Or trying to give to this empty element a value, the console throws me an error like "Cannot read property 'array' of undefined"

How can I fix this?

I hope you can help me, thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `array.filter((item) => item)`

Comment: please add the array.

Comment: Use `filter()` which will remove elements you don't want. `forEach` is just an iterator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `filter` method

```js
const data = ["", undefined, 2, "abc", null];

// Method 1 filter method
const res = data.filter((x) => x);

// Alternatively
const res2 = data.filter(Boolean);

console.log(res);
console.log(res2);
```